# Trying to create a dynamic link with API and React router, console is showing [object%20Object].json 404?

Tags: redux, axios, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

I'm currently working on a site that pulls Reddit data from different subreddits to show recipes, you can toggle between 3 different ones. That part works fine! I'm able to pull the list of posts from each subreddit, but now I'm trying to make it so when you click a button, it routes you to post details where it'll show the post and comments. I have to do another API call to get that information.

Somewhere along the way, it's getting messed up and it's showing "xhr.js:210 GET [https://www.reddit.com/r/recipes/comments/[object%20Object].json](https://www.reddit.com/r/recipes/comments/%5Bobject%20Object%5D.json) 404:" It's a dynamic route, so there are two different parameters I'm trying to use. I did try and console log the parameter for ID(the one showing up as [object object] and it shows up fine by itself and is not an object from what I  can tell.

Please see some of the code below where I think things could be going wrong. I'm guessing it's the API call because when I console log it, it only shows the subreddit as an arg but not sure..

redditAPI.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://www.reddit.com/r/"
})
```

store.js:

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import postReducer from './posts/postSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        posts: postReducer
    }
});
```

postSlice.js:

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import redditApi from '../../common/api/redditApi';
import { redditDetails } from '../../common/api/redditApi';

export const fetchAsyncPosts = createAsyncThunk('posts/fetchAsyncPosts', async (subreddit) => {
    const response = await redditApi.get(subreddit)
    return response.data.data.children;
});

export const fetchAsyncPostsDetail = createAsyncThunk('posts/fetchAsyncPostsDetail', async (sub, postID) => {
    const response = await redditApi.get(`${sub}/comments/${postID}.json`)
    return response.data.data.children;
});



const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    selectedSubreddit: 'recipes.json',
    selectedPost: []
}

const postSlice = createSlice({
    name: "posts",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
    addPosts: (state, { payload }) => {
        state.posts = payload;
    },
    addSelectedPost: (state, {payload}) => {
        state.selectedPost = payload;
    },
    setSelectedSubreddit(state, action) {
        state.selectedSubreddit = action.payload;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
      [fetchAsyncPosts.pending] : () => {
          console.log("Pending");
      },
      [fetchAsyncPosts.fulfilled] : (state, {payload}) => {
          console.log("Fulfilled");
          return {...state, posts: payload};
      },
      [fetchAsyncPosts.rejected]: () => {
          console.log("Rejected");
      },
      [fetchAsyncPostsDetail.fulfilled] : (state, {payload}) => {
        console.log("Fulfilled");
        return {...state, selectedPost: payload};
      },
    },
});

export const {addPosts, setSelectedSubreddit} = postSlice.actions;
export const selectSelectedSubreddit = (state) => state.selectedSubreddit;
export const getAllPosts = (state) => state.posts.posts;
export const getSelectedPost = (state) => state.posts.selectedPost;
export default postSlice.reducer;
```

App.js

```
import "./App.scss";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import PageNotFound from "./components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import PostDetails from "./components/PostDetails/PostDetails";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <Router>
        <Header/>
         <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/:sub/comments/:postID" element={<PostDetails />} />
          <Route path="*" element={ <PageNotFound />} />
         </Routes>

      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import PostListing from '../PostListing/PostListing'
import { fetchAsyncPosts } from '../../features-redux/posts/postSlice';

function Home() {
 
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const subreddit = useSelector((state) => state.posts.selectedSubreddit);
  
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchAsyncPosts(subreddit));
    }, [dispatch, subreddit]);

 
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div className="container text-center">
                     <h1 className="display-4">Welcome to Tasteful Reddit</h1>
                    <p className="lead">Toggle between subreddits above to view their recipes.</p>
                 </div>
        </div>
            <PostListing />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

postListing.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getAllPosts } from '../../features-redux/posts/postSlice'
import PostCard from '../PostCard/PostCard';

function PostListing() {
    const posts = useSelector(getAllPosts);
    

    const rendering = () => posts.map((post, key) => {
        return <PostCard key={key} data={post.data} />;
    });

    console.log(posts);

    return (
        <div className="post-wrapper">
            <div className="post-container">
             {rendering()}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostListing
```

postCard.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

 function PostCard(props) {
    const {data} = props;

   /* Function to change escaped HTML to string */
    const htmlDecode = (input) => {
        var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
        return doc.documentElement.textContent;
      }

    /* Decode reddit JSON's youtube embed HTML */
    const youtubeHtmlString = htmlDecode(data.media_embed.content);
   

    /* This function runs through the reddit data to make sure that there is a 
    an image for the post. If so, shows image
    and if its a reddit hosted video or youtube video it will render the video. 
    Gallery-style posts & all else shows empty div*/
  
    const mediaRender = () => {
        if (data.thumbnail !== 'self' && data.thumbnail !== 'default' && data.is_self !== true && data.is_gallery !== true && data.domain !== 'youtu.be' && data.domain !== 'v.redd.it') {
        return <img src = {data.url} alt={data.title} className="card-img-top"/>;   
        } if ( data.is_video == true) {
            return (
            <div>
                <video controls preload = "none">
                    <source src={data.media.reddit_video.fallback_url} type="video/mp4"/>
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>
          ) 
        } if (data.domain == 'youtu.be') {
            return (
                <div className="Container">
                    {parse(youtubeHtmlString)}
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return <div></div>
        }       
    }

    /* If only text & no photos, render text info*/

    const renderSelf = () => {
        if(data.is_self == true) {
            return (<p>{data.selftext}</p>)
        } else {
            return <p></p>
        }
    }

    return (
             <div className="card mb-3 mx-auto text-center" style={{width: "70%"}}>
            <div className="row g-0">
                <div className="col-md-5">
                {mediaRender()}
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-7">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{parse(data.title)}</h5>
                    <div className="card-text">{renderSelf()}</div>
                    <div className="card-text"><small className="text-muted">By {data.author}</small></div>
                    <Link to={`/${data.subreddit}/comments/${data.id}`}>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary">Go to post</button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div> 


    )
    }

export default PostCard
```

postDetails.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { fetchAsyncPostsDetail, getSelectedPost } from '../../features-redux/posts/postSlice';

function PostDetails() {
    let {sub, postID} = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const data = useSelector(getSelectedPost);
    console.log(postID)
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchAsyncPostsDetail(sub, postID));
        console.log(dispatch(fetchAsyncPostsDetail(sub, postID)))
    }, [dispatch, postID, sub]);

    console.log(data);

    return (
        <div>
            PostDetails
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostDetails
```

Any help would be appreciated, because I'm lost!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out today, for those interested!

I finally got it! I figured I was doing something wrong with react router, and that's why I couldn't get it to work but I didn't want to stop using react router. I tried many different ways to fix it, including putting both arguments in an object, I tried changing it by passing what I needed with a pathname AND a state, but the state didn't work right.  think that I was passing the state in an incorrect way somehow. I think I wrote it like state{ permalink: data.permalink} or something. I also tried changing it so it only took one parameter, but for some reason the react router Link only wanted to use the post IDs and would go to my page not found if I tried to use permalink. After researching other ways to pass data using React Router, I landed on using From to grab the data from the previous page the user was on and used useLocation to grab the state.

Here is a snippet of what I changed in Link for in PostCard.js. The data was passed in props from postListing.js, just for reference:

```
return (
            <div className="card mb-3 mx-auto text-center" style={{width: "70%"}}>
               <div className="row g-0">
                 <div className="col-md-5">
                    {mediaRender()}
                 </div>
                <div className="col-md-7">
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{parse(data.title)}</h5>
                    <div className="card-text">{renderSelf()}</div>
                    <div className="card-text"><small className="text-muted">By {data.author}</small></div>
                        <Link to={`/post/${data.id}`}
                         state={{ from: data}}>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary">Go to post</button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div> 


    )
    }
```

I also stopped using the postId to try and make the API call, and instead only used it to make the dynamic link to the component. After that, I used From's state to grab the permalink(from previous reddit post data) to make the API call to get the comment information.

Here is a snippet of PostDetails.js where I made the changes:

```
function PostDetails() {
    const location = useLocation();
    const {from} = location.state;
    const comments = useSelector(getSelectedPost);

    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
       
    useEffect( () => {
        dispatch(getPostComments(from.permalink));
    }, [dispatch]);
```

I also found out I was trying to access the data incorrectly in my API call, as the data was structured differently than I originally thought.

Here is the changed thunk in PostSlice.js:

```
export const getPostComments = createAsyncThunk('posts/getPostComments', async (permalink) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://www.reddit.com${permalink}.json`);
    const json = await response.json();
  
    return json[1].data.children.map((comment) => comment.data)
  });
```

There were multiple things wrong with my react app, but hopefully this helps someone else! :)

Comment: It's good that you figured it all out, and this is a nice description. It might be nice if you could post a few brief relevant snippets of code related to what you got working.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `createAsyncThunk` is the [`payloadCreator`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator).

It's called with two arguments, `arg` which is a single value, and the `thunkAPI` object.

> ```
> // First, create the thunk
> const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
>   'users/fetchByIdStatus',
>   async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
>     const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId)
>     return response.data
>   }
> )
>
> // Later, dispatch the thunk as needed in the app
> dispatch(fetchUserById(123))
> ```

You are passing the `thunkAPI` argument as the `postID` value in the GET request.

```
export const fetchAsyncPostsDetail = createAsyncThunk(
  'posts/fetchAsyncPostsDetail',
   async (sub, postID) => {
    const response = await redditApi.get(`${sub}/comments/${postID}.json`)
    return response.data.data.children;
  }
);
```

If you need to pass multiple values to your thunk then pack them into a single object.

```
export const fetchAsyncPostsDetail = createAsyncThunk(
  'posts/fetchAsyncPostsDetail',
   async ({ sub, postID }, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await redditApi.get(`${sub}/comments/${postID}.json`)
    return response.data.data.children;
  }
);
```

...

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchAsyncPostsDetail({ sub, postID }));
}, [dispatch, postID, sub]);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! That makes sense in terms of putting them in a single object, but when I tried to do that it came up as Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () with a weird looking link: https://www.reddit.com/r/function%20sub()%20%7B%20[native%20code]%20%7D/comments/undefined.json Any idea what it could be?

Comment: @Tay_ Hmm, seems the `sub` match param value comes from the `data` (`data.subreddit`) prop passed as `<PostCard key={key} data={post.data} />`. Is this `subreddit` value what you expect it to be in the link? Trace the `sub` value from `PostDetails` and in `fetchAsyncPostsDetail` (just console log it). Is it what you expect it to be the entire way through to the GET request? It also looks like `postId` is undefined in the request URL.

Comment: So I console logged everywhere, and the sub and id values are showing correctly when I click on different posts and shows up logged in the postDetails. It's definitely the id that's having issues though! I checked the API call again, and it's still only showing one arg (the subreddit) and not showing the secondary arg for id. I'll mess around with it more tomorrow when I work on it again. Thanks!!

Comment: @Tay_ No worries, thanks for checking the values via logs. If possible, think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: I ended up still trying to see if I could figure it out tonight. I made a running codesandbox at https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigilant-kalam-tn204?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The console logs are strange. The id specifically shows as what it's supposed to be and then goes undefined later in the API call. I can't figure out what exactly would fix it. I've been trying to console log different areas to see where it's going wrong